# 할 말을 잃다 vs 할 말을 잊다

Tags: difference, idiom, phrase-meaning

"할 말을 잃다."  literally translates to

> (Subject) loses (잃다) words (말) to say (말하다).

"할 말을 잊다." is literally

> (Subject) forgets (잊다) words (말) to say (말하다).

Both sentences sound very confusing as in

> 그가 한 짓은 나에게 할 말을 **잃게** / **잊게** 만들었다.
>
> (Literally) What he did made me lose / forget words to say.

Is there any difference in their meaning and usage?

Answer (score 2):

From Naver's online dictionary:

[잃다](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&query=%EC%9E%83%EB%8B%A4&preQuery=dlfgek&searchOption=all&forceRedirect=N):
(물건·집·자리 등을) lose; (빼앗기다) be deprived of

[잊다](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&dicQuery=%EC%9E%8A%EB%8B%A4&x=0&y=0&query=%EC%9E%8A%EB%8B%A4&target=endic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=N)
(기억하지 못하다) forget

잃다 is used when you forget or lose material possession. It is also used when you are unable to find the way to go your destination.

잊다 is used when you forget something you knew previously but cannot recall it at the moment

[This post](http://blog.naver.com/sorang2012/220163094482) has some explanation in detail:
[image]

It also has an explanation for the specific sentence in question:
[image]

할말을 잃었다:  When you run out of words/have nothing more to say/get stumped by the other person's logic etc

할말을 잊었다:  When you cannot recall what to say/forget something you knew earlier etc